# Tension along a uniformly charged rod of finite length

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electricity

I was trying to calculate the tension along a uniformly charged rod of finite length, however, the tension diverged.[image]

Translation: 'Let a uniformly charged rod of linear charge density λ and length L. Make a graph of the magnitude of the tension T(r) along the rod.

My idea was to consider two separate parts of the bar at a given point of distance r to one of the extremities of the bar; then we calculate the force between one infinitesimal sections in each bar, and integrate to find the total electric force between the left and the right parts. However, as you can see in the picture, it gave me a "ln(0)" term around the end, so that must mean this force must diverge.

This was shocking to me, since it doesn't look like an unconceivable system physically. I was wondering whether I am mistaken, and if there's any literature I could look into that discusses this.

Observation: I am not a student and this is not homework.

Comment: Please avoid sending screenshots: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/discouraging-the-use-of-textual-screenshots-in-questions

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are not implausible.  The problem is that Coulomb's Law is poorly behaved when it deals with infinite charge densities.  It is impossible to realize a one-dimensional "line charge" in the real world, and Coulomb's Law blows up in this limit.

If you were to do the same calculation for a uniformly charged cylinder with charge $q$, length $L$, and radius $\epsilon$, I suspect that the result would be well-behaved so long as you had $\epsilon \neq 0$. (It would be a difficult calculation, but the result wouldn't be divergent.)